# What is this thing?

Tags: audio, microphone, 3.5mm

I have a piece of hardware that my grandma gave me along with her old laptop.  I have no idea what it is and neither does anyone I know.  It has a mono 3.5mm plug on one end, but plugging it into a headphone jack does nothing.  Same result with a microphone jack.  It has a 16 foot long cable.  Pictures below.

[image: both ends]

[image: unknown end]

[image: 3.5mm end]

Can someone please tell me what it is, what it does, and how to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like an infrared sender. Old method of communication on some laptops, and external tools, though it depends on the frequency of light it puts out. That's all I can see it doing.

Normally the receivers are not clear, that is usually the sender. If it was a receiver it would be similar to the one in Kamil's answer, with a filtered input so that it doesn't confuse the incoming signals.

Comment: how would I use it?  does it plug into the mic port?

Comment: If you plugged it into a mic port it may turn on but it would be useless, unless you wanted to program your sounds to output a specific signal. :P 
Usually there is an Infrared sender port on a device like a remote that it would get plugged into and then you would point it at the TV. Very basic.

Answer (score 6):

I used to have a TV card with a remote. The remote receiver was an IR diode in a casing, connected to the card via mini jack – just like the thing in question.

Notice the "REMOTE" label below:

[image: TV card]

The receiver itself:

[image: receiver]

Technically those things may send signals (like the other answer suggests) even if they were designed as receivers, I think. Still my bet is your mysterious item is a receiver shipped with some device and an IR remote.

Comment: Normally the receivers are not clear, that is usually the sender, if it was a receiver it would be similar to yours, with a filtered input so that it doesn't confuse the incoming signals.

Comment: @cengbrecht You are probably right. I have added your comment to your answer because I think it is relevant and interesting; it surely belongs there as well.